# meteor with angular 2 final version?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular, angular-meteor

Is there any way to use the angular 2 final version with meteor right now?, or should we wait for any updated version from meteor?
Im now using meteor 1.4.1 and I think it consist on rc4

Comment: We have it working. In order to release we are updating the tutorials first (Waiting for Ionic to catch up on Angular 2.0 final) and also doing some re-ordering.  Hopefully we'll get everything done very soon

Answer (score 1):

As I see Angular2-meteor is already up to date with the release version.

[Angular2-meteor repository](https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor/commit/f7af9b2ae0734e2ce1b313f39c238582cc6392e2

The last commit targets release 2.0.0.

So I would say it's release-ready :)